# Insert Multiple Rows in SQLite Error (error code = 1)

Tags: android, android-sqlite, bulkinsert

I am getting an error when executing the following query in SQLite Android

```
sDataBase.execSQL(query);
```

> insert into Contacts(ID,FirstName,LastName,PhoneNumber,EmailId,Status)
>   values('ae0caa6a-8ff6-d63f-0253-110b20ac2127','xxx','xxx','9008987887','xxx@gmail.com','Yes'),('9afab56e-a18a-47f2-fd62-35c78d8e0d94','yyy','yyy','7890988909','yyy@gmail.com','Yes'),('378d757a-ee60-07a4-e8bc-396b402c3270','zzz','zzz','9000898454','zzz@gmail.com','Yes')

**Note: This is executed fine in SQLServer, getting error in Android
SQLite.**

```
Error: sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near ",": syntax error, db=/data/data/myapp.contactmanager/databases/webview.db
```

**EDIT 1: I have added space between values still getting error**

```
insert into Contacts(ID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, EmailId,Status) values
('ae0caa6a-8ff6-d63f-0253-110b20ac2127', 'xxx', 'xxx','9008987887', 'xxx@gmail.com', 'Yes'), 
('9afab56e-a18a-47f2-fd62-35c78d8e0d94', 'yyy', 'yyy', '7890988909', 'yyy@gmail.com', 'Yes'), 
('378d757a-ee60-07a4-e8bc-396b402c3270', 'zzz', 'zzz', '9000898454', 'zzz@gmail.com', 'Yes')
```

**Edit 2: Changed the query using [Is it possible to insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database) still not working**

```
INSERT INTO Contacts 
SELECT 'ae0caa6a-8ff6-d63f-0253-110b20ac2127' AS ID, 'xxx' AS FirstName, 'xxx' AS LastName, '9008987887' AS PhoneNumber, 'xxx@gmail.com' AS EmailId, 'Yes' AS Status, 
UNION SELECT '9afab56e-a18a-47f2-fd62-35c78d8e0d94', 'yyy', 'yyy', '7890988909', 'yyy@gmail.com', 'Yes' 
UNION SELECT '378d757a-ee60-07a4-e8bc-396b402c3270', 'zzz', 'zzz', '9000898454', 'zzz@gmail.com', 'Yes'
```

**Edit 3:** I have did a small mistake in the Edit 2. End of Sync status that is `before UNION i have included comma`, so that i got an error. Now removed and **working fine**.

```
INSERT INTO Contacts 
SELECT 'ae0caa6a-8ff6-d63f-0253-110b20ac2127' AS ID, 'xxx' AS FirstName, 'xxx' AS LastName, '9008987887' AS PhoneNumber, 'xxx@gmail.com' AS EmailId, 'Yes' AS Status 
UNION SELECT '9afab56e-a18a-47f2-fd62-35c78d8e0d94', 'yyy', 'yyy', '7890988909', 'yyy@gmail.com', 'Yes' 
UNION SELECT '378d757a-ee60-07a4-e8bc-396b402c3270', 'zzz', 'zzz', '9000898454', 'zzz@gmail.com', 'Yes'
```

Comment: i think you should add white space after "," in the query

Comment: @Shiv: I have tried that also

Comment: check whether the table name in SQLite database and your code is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you insert multiple rows in SQLite. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database) for details.

If I were you, go with either the syntax in that question's answer OR, if you want to be able to insert a single row at once too, just do a standard `INSERT INTO db (one, two) VALUES (one, two)` and execute that once for each row you're inserting. Up to you!

Comment: Please tell me what mistake in my input

Comment: Inserting multiple values like that is valid in MySQL, but not SQLite; you have to use different syntax. Read the post I linked.

Comment: Interesting - in that case, use the answer provided by @Sajmon - Unless you really have to hardcode stuff, that's a much better way to do it.

Comment: I have solved my insert multiple row issue by the link that you have provided. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

> Insert Multiple Rows in SQLite Error

I really don't like your approach. It's so hardcored and it looks like spaghetti code. And your approach never will work because **one insert can have only one values**. So you are doing it incorrect.
What about to use `API insert()` method that it directly designed for inserting?

Also from point of view about speed performance and security i recommend you to use `TRANSACTION` as well. But let's go to write some code especially for you.

```
public void insertMultiple(List<Contact> contacts) {
    Contact c = null;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    try {
        if (db != null) {
            db.beginTransaction();
            for (Contact c: contacts) {
                values.put(SQLConstants.FIRSTNAME, c.getFirstName());
                values.put(SQLConstants.LASTNAME, c.getLastName());
                ...
                db.insertOrThrow("Contacts", SQLConstants.FIRSTNAME, values);
                values.clear();
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }
    }
    finally {
        if (db != null && db.inTransaction()) {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    }
}
```

### Notes:

As i noticed you have table called **Constacts** so i suggest you to create **own Object Contact** that will represent your table on application layer where properties of object are equal to columns in table. I recommend you to use this approach because:

- It's not spagetthi code
- It's pretty faster
- It's much more safe

### A few suggestions at the end:

`execSQL()` is not bad but i'm using it generally only when i create `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass for creating and deleting and altering tables. There an usage is pretty suitable. But as main recommendations to you are:

- Everytime you are inserting, updating, deleting an usage of
  transaction is always very good practice, because except increase of
  speed performance(especially if you are insert great number of rows)
  is your works with database much more safe.

<sub>**Only for info:** I did a few tests when i inserted 1000, 10 000, 100 000 rows into SQLite and i can tell you that inserting of 100 000 rows took only **55,346** seconds. Inserting of 1 000 rows without transaction took even **73,398** seconds.</sub>

- Everytime you are selecting, inserting, updating from one or more tables use **placeholders** i.e.
  parametrized statements and not hardcoded. With it, your queries will
  become safer, faster and better human-readable. In the case of joining always use join clause. It's best you can choose.

### Update:

Here is working your code:

```
insert into Contacts(ID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, EmailId, Status) 
select 'someId' as ID, 'xxx' as FirstName, 'xxx' as LastName , '9008987887' as PhoneNumber , 'xxx@gmail.com' as EmaiId, 'Yes' as Status
union all select 'someId', 'xxx', 'xxx', '9008987887', 'xxx@gmail.com', 'Yes'
union all select 'someId', 'xxx', 'xxx', '9008987887', 'xxx@gmail.com', 'Yes'
```

### Update 2:

As @Korniltsev Anatoly pointed out in SQLite there is a constraint `SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT` that means that you cannot use more than 500 unions at once.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have passed query from web page (Cross Platform Actions). May be you are right. but i want to clear errors in my query only

Comment: @Ponmalar you wont clear errors because your approach is not correct and never will work. you can have only one values per one insert.. not two, not three only one.

Comment: Please see the Edit 3. I have worked out this without union all

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Sajmon 's answer:

It is worth to mention that there is a limitation in sqlite - **SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT** which is **500** or greater on almost all devices. It means that you can not use more than 500 unions at once. If you'l use more - your sql query may fail.