# Insert or Replace Multiple Row with where condition in SQLite Query

Tags: android, android-sqlite, bulkinsert

I need a single SQLite query to insert or update in SQLite table.

**MyTable:**

1. **Id**(Primary key and not null)
2. **Name**
3. **PhoneNumber**

[image]

> **Expected Query**: If the Id is not present then have to insert a new row
> and If the existing row value is changed then update the row when inserting multiple row.

**EDIT 1:**

I have posted INSERT query i have tried in [Insert Multiple Rows in SQLite Error (error code = 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613377/insert-multiple-rows-in-sqlite-error-error-code-1). Like that i I have tried using "INSERT OR REPLACE". But it is `working with Firfox SQLite Manager Not working with Android SQLite`.

I have used `sDataBase.execSQL(query)` to execute this query.

Comment: Just a note that may help someone.  It **is** perfectly OK to have a batch command (so .. values (...) , (...) , (...) and so on) with "insert or replace".

Comment: Just another note that may help someone  :)  interestingly performance tests show that "insert or replace" is very little slower (5% at worst) than plain "insert".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created database with primary key only in Firefox SQLite Manager. I have missed this in SQLite database in Android. Now i have **`created database with PRIMARY KEY and NOT NULL`**. **Now Working fine**.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO MyTable (Name, PhoneNumber) VALUES (?,?)";
SQLiteStatement st = db.compileStatement(sql);
```

And write or update:

```
    public void writeOrUpdateData(ArrayList<MyClass> data) {
    try {

        db.beginTransaction();

        for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {

            st.clearBindings();
            st.bindLong(1, data.get(i).getName());
            st.bindString(2, data.get(i).getPhoneNumber);
            st.executeInsert();

        }

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();

    } 
    catch(Exception e) {} 
    finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

This way you get bulk insert/update, which is quite efficient!

Comment: Multiple row will not be working with your query. I have tried.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database

Comment: @Ponmalar Emm, I expect that you have some custom class objects, which you want to write/update in local sqlite db. So bulk insert/update would work just fine. Pass multiple objects within ArrayList

Comment: Thanks for your response. i am sending query from webview. Inside WebView I will execute the query using sDataBase.execSQL(query); So I need a query only